# find and rename files gives bash 'no such file or directory' error

Tags: bash, sed, find

I'm trying to strip the numbers and  `-` from the file name.

Below are the files.

```
ui-service-3.100.503505.json
kibana-store-end-3.103.103505.json
api-application-3.4003.10350665.json

find . -type f -iname "*.json"  -exec rename 's/[0-9]//g' {} \;
```

throws `find: ‘rename’: No such file or directory`

Tried multiple other combinations but same error.

I'm expecting below output, where am I going wrong ?

```
ui-service.json
kibana-store-end.json
api-application.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't have `rename` command on your system. Try this instead:

```
for file in ./*.json; do
    echo mv "$file" "${file%-*}.json"
done
```

Drop the `echo` if the output looks fine.

Comment: I always recommend `mv -i` or `-n` for any bulk/automated move, to avoid overwriting files in case there's a name conflict.

Comment: @Nejat : Looping is working for me but I wanted to try via `find` command.
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @ChelMS `find` gains you nothing over the plain `bash` version, for this particular task. If you want to recurse into subdirectories, then use `for file in ./**/*.json` after setting the `globstar` option.